# Python3 update & write JSON values

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm new to writing Python and ran into a bit of a roadblock. I'm trying to add new information to the following example json file

```
{
  "data1": {
    "info1": [
      {
        "keyA1": "valueA1",
        "keyA2": "valueA2"
      },
      {
        "keyB1": "valueB1",
        "KeyB2": "valueB2"
      }
    ],
    "info2": {
        "keyA1": "valueA1",
        "keyA2": "valueA2"
    }
  }
}
```

I've scooped up the json file with:

`myData = json.load(open('cool.json', encoding='utf-8'))`

Now I have myData that I can use well enough. However, when it comes to updating there are three situations that I can't get to work correctly. I need to be able to:

1. Change the data in info2 to an array (`"info2": [` vs `"info2": {`) and add another
   keyB1 similar to what is in info1.
2. Add a whole new section called data2

Once the editing is done, I'd dump `myData` back to a file to write it, which I got working. I know my new-ness is showing and it's probably something easy I'm just missing. I'm familiar with `myData.update(newData)` but can't get the array and new section figured out. Any help would be appreciated.

Currently, I have:

```
def dataAdd(value1, value2, dataSet, infoSet):
    if dataSet in myData.keys():
        newEntry = {"keyA1": value1, "keyA2": value2}
        myData[dataSet].update({infoSet:newEntry})
        with open('cool.json', "w") as jsonFile:
            json.dump(myData, jsonFile)
```

Currently, the above code will add as expected, but overwrites existing keys. This is why I'm trying to convert to an array when adding a second set.

Comment: Please show your code so far

Comment: Did you try `myData['data1']['info2'] = [dict(myData['data1']['info2'])]` and for `data2` new section `myData['data2'] = {}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you gotta do:

```py
>>> import json
>>> # pprint is just for a nice printed output
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> json_text = '''
... {
...   "data1": {
...     "info1": [
...       {
...         "keyA1": "valueA1",
...         "keyA2": "valueA2"
...       },
...       {
...         "keyB1": "valueB1",
...         "KeyB2": "valueB2"
...       }
...     ],
...     "info2": {
...         "keyA1": "valueA1",
...         "keyA2": "valueA2"
...     }
...   }
... }
... '''
>>> 
>>> myData = json.loads(json_text)

>>> pprint(myData)
{'data1': {'info1': [{'keyA1': 'valueA1', 'keyA2': 'valueA2'},
                     {'KeyB2': 'valueB2', 'keyB1': 'valueB1'}],
           'info2': {'keyA1': 'valueA1', 'keyA2': 'valueA2'}}}
>>> 

>>> # Convert to a list of dicionaries
>>> myData['data1']['info2'] = [myData['data1']['info2']]

>>> # Add a new section
>>> myData['data2'] = {}

>>> # Print the final result
>>> pprint(myData)
{'data1': {'info1': [{'keyA1': 'valueA1', 'keyA2': 'valueA2'},
                     {'KeyB2': 'valueB2', 'keyB1': 'valueB1'}],
           'info2': [{'keyA1': 'valueA1', 'keyA2': 'valueA2'}]},
 'data2': {}}
>>>

>>> # Just forgot to add those new keys you mentioned in your question
>> myData['data1']['info2'].append({'keyB1': 'valueB1', 'keyB2': 'valueB2'})

>>> pprint(myData['data1']['info2'])
[{'keyA1': 'valueA1', 'keyA2': 'valueA2'},
 {'keyB1': 'valueB1', 'keyB2': 'valueB2'}]
>>> 

>>> pprint(myData)
{'data1': {'info1': [{'keyA1': 'valueA1', 'keyA2': 'valueA2'},
                     {'KeyB2': 'valueB2', 'keyB1': 'valueB1'}],
           'info2': [{'keyA1': 'valueA1', 'keyA2': 'valueA2'},
                     {'keyB1': 'valueB1', 'keyB2': 'valueB2'}]},
 'data2': {}}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I will give this a run and check back.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you very much... for your help and patience.

Comment: No worries. I'm glad it worked as you was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing:

```
new_data = myData.update(...)
```

`.update()` function return `None`, so you should

```
myData.update(...)
```

Then you have `myData` updated and ready to be written.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question -

```
myData['data1']['info2'] = [myData['data1']['info2']]
```

For second, it is similar to how you add new keys to a dict()